# PHP Format variable

Tags: php

I have a variable as shown below with upper case initials and a space. What would be ideal way to format so that it lower case the initials and puts `"-"` dash in between. So end result should be `"los-angeles"`:

```
$city = "Los Angeles";
```

convert to

```
$city ="los-angeles";
```

Comment: are you trying to create a part of url?

Comment: Is that a *How can I convert a document title into a URL slug?* question?

Comment: not the document title though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($city));
```

But if you're trying to create url it won't be enough.

Comment: Mann i loveeee stackoverflow cant get better than this. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish your specific task, you'd do:

```
$city = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($city));
```

But, if you're doing this so that the string will work in a URL (as the comments have suggested), you should do:

```
$city = urlencode($city);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function slug($str)
{
    $str = strtolower(trim($str));
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', '-', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/-+/', "-", $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Assuming you're talking about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /** method slugify
    * 
    * cleans up a string such as a page title
    * so it becomes a readable valid url
    *
    * @param STR a string
    * @return STR a url friendly slug
    **/

    function slugifyAlnum( $str ){

    $str = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]#i', ' ', $str );    // allow letter and numbers only
    $str = preg_replace('#( ){2,}#', ' ', $str );       // rm adjacent spaces

    return strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '-', $str ) ); // slugify


    }
```

Funny, I was working on this today, I trim it before sending it here, this func is for when Users are permitted to create a page title which you want to use to create a slug for mod_rewrite etc.

Allow for usual f-ups like more than one space, sticking non-alnum chars in it etc